What kind of "superintellect that monkeyed with physics" did Sir Fred Hoyle have in mind given that he was an atheist?
The Wikipedia article on Fred Hoyle introduces him as follows:

Sir Fred Hoyle FRS (24 June 1915 – 20 August 2001)[1] was an English astronomer who formulated the theory of stellar nucleosynthesis and was one of the authors of the influential B2FH paper. He also held controversial stances on other scientific matters—in particular his rejection of the "Big Bang" theory (a term coined by him on BBC Radio) in favor of the "steady-state model", and his promotion of panspermia as the origin of life on Earth.[3][4][5] He spent most of his working life at St John's College, Cambridge and served as the founding director of the Institute of Theoretical Astronomy at Cambridge.

The following quotes from the article are pertinent to the present question:

This energy level, while needed to produce carbon in large quantities,
was statistically very unlikely to fall where it does in the scheme of
carbon energy levels. Hoyle later wrote:

Would you not say to yourself, "Some super-calculating intellect must
have designed the properties of the carbon atom, otherwise the chance
of my finding such an atom through the blind forces of nature would be
utterly minuscule. A common sense interpretation of the facts suggests
that a superintellect has monkeyed with physics, as well as with
chemistry and biology, and that there are no blind forces worth
speaking about in nature. The numbers one calculates from the facts
seem to me so overwhelming as to put this conclusion almost beyond
question."

— Fred Hoyle[24]


Though Hoyle declared himself an atheist,[38] this apparent suggestion of a guiding hand led him to the conclusion that "a superintellect has monkeyed with physics, as well as with chemistry and biology, and ... there are no blind forces worth speaking about in nature."[39] He would go on to compare the random emergence of even the simplest cell without panspermia to the likelihood that "a tornado sweeping through a junk-yard might assemble a Boeing 747 from the materials therein" and to compare the chance of obtaining even a single functioning protein by chance combination of amino acids to a solar system full of blind men solving Rubik's Cubes simultaneously.[40] This is known as "the junkyard tornado",[41] or "Hoyle's Fallacy". Those who advocate the intelligent design (ID) philosophy sometimes cite Hoyle's work in this area to support the claim that the universe was fine tuned to allow intelligent life to be possible.

As the last quoted paragraph indicates, Hoyle is sometimes cited by ID supporters. However, Hoyle declared himself to be an atheist. So, if God was out of the picture for Hoyle, what kind "superintellect that monkeyed with physics" did Hoyle have in mind?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


"So, if God was out of the picture for Hoyle, what kind "superintellect that monkeyed with physics" did Hoyle have in mind?"

Hoyle used the word "monkeyed" an absolute past participle.
Hoyle dated the universe at billions plus years old, and actually expected it was eternal.
So the only thing he has expressed suspicion of, is...

Something, billions of years ago, may have chosen the laws of physics.

That is a huge difference from the Christian...

Thousands or billions of years a thinking agent designed and created the universe, and now today is watching and listening and answering and manipulating and judging and will provide access to a heavenly eternity after-life.

From Standford University religious club comes this collection of popular icons to remind us it is not a dichotomy.

To go from "monkeyed with physics" to "God" is a leap that is not philosophically sound.
Unless he said other stuff, like "I Hoyle think there is a God".  But I haven't read that anywhere.

"To go from "monkeyed with physics" to "God" is a leap that is not philosophically sound."  What sort of next step in the exploration of the idea of "something choosing" the laws of physics would you consider philosophically sound?  It seems like one of the most momentous unanswered questions out there, it deserves further consideration does it not?  Or do we shrug our shoulders and turn our attention to more important questions like the meaning of "I" in "I think, therefore I am" or "how can we ever know whether someone raised their arm voluntarily or not?"

It is a leap in a specific direction without any indicator causing reason to leap in a specific direction.

Would not some testimonial evidence (from an atheist scientist no less!) indicating the possibility of a super intelligent being with the power and will to establish precise physical laws be an "indicator" to seek further understanding of the nature of this being?

@MichaelHall "Would not some testimonial evidence (from an atheist scientist no less!) indicating the possibility of a super intelligent being with the power and will to establish precise physical laws be an "indicator" to seek further understanding of the nature of this being?"... only if one was agreed with his assessment which is a provably underinformed opinion.

If we are putting weight on the words of an individual because they are a scientist, then we should be fair to their memory by reviewing all of their statements on a subject, not just pick and choose.  For example, while he did make the "monkeyed with" comment, it is also reported... While having no argument with the Lemaître theory that the universe was expanding, Hoyle disagreed on its interpretation. He found the idea that the universe had a beginning to be pseudoscience, resembling arguments for a creator, "for it's an irrational process, and can't be described in scientific terms"

@MichaelHall When you look at your phone, do you jump to an almighty creator who cares personally about you? Why would you look at the universe, if it is created, and jump to it being a solitary creator? God also tends to imply omniscience, omnipotence, and omnibenevolence, when the creator could be an outerworldly scientist as limited in capacity to completely understand or modify the experiment as a human experimenter; perhaps we aren't even at a scale the creator can detect.

Hoyle was a scientist and cosmologist.  And scientists follow the evidence, and cosmologists have followed the find tuning evidence and basically reached a consensus that our universe exhibits apparent fine tuning. He also accepted the creationist calculations on the improbability of biomolecular evolution
HOWEVER, as Kuhn and Lakatos have pointed out about science, one need not reject a paradigm even if one has a refuting test case or two. One can, instead, treat the addressing of that refuting test case as a "to do" task.  Hoyle did not need to accept theism based on apparent fine tuning, or the difficulty of biomolecular evolution, so long as he was still working on finding some other way to account for them.
I think we can reject the creationist probability case against biomolecular evolution, given the demonstrated evolutionary changes in influenza viruses every year.
The creationist argument against abiogenesis is very possibly more substantial.
The reason that most cosmologists today are multiverse advocates is because a multiverse provides a non-theist way to explain apparent fine tuning.  the challenge that a multiverse seems to lead to unfalsifiability in worldview, however, is a problem for this answer.
So the "to do" programme is still a work in progress.
